# How can I write a view that pulls an image from my local resources and if it's not there pull the image from SF Symbols

Tags: image, swiftui

I have written this to either pull my icons from my own resources in my project or pull them from SF Symbols in SwiftUI. Unfortunately, I get No such module 'UIKit'.  I've also tried to import UIKit.UIImage.  Has this functionality been deprecated or has it picked up and moved elsewhere?  Or am I just doing this wrong?

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

struct GetImage: View {
    let name: String
    
    init(_ name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        if let image = UIImage(named: name) {
            return Image( uiImage: image )
        } else {
            return Image( systemName: name )
        }
    }
}
```

Edit-2 - works but doesn't allow modifiers

```
import SwiftUI

struct MyImage: View {
     let image: String
     
     init(_ image: String) {
          self.image = image
     }
     
     var body: some View {
         if ( NSImage(named: image) != nil ) {
            print( " ---> a" )
            return Image( image )
        } else {
            print( " ---> b" )
            return Image( systemName: image )
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Are you building for iOS, macOS, watchOS? UIKit is not available in some platforms.

Comment: Right now I'm building for MacOS but planning on iOS eventually

Comment: NSImage or CGImage, UIImage isnt available.

Comment: OK, then can I do this same thing without these alternate Classes of Image (NS, CG or UI)?  I'm would hope that Image() would return the same exists type information.  if let image = Image( name ).

Comment: Image is a View, it isn't equivalent to the others. It is much more limited.

Comment: No... that doesn't work.  Evidently there is something called an optional type and Image() doesn't qualify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is another approach and the code works on both macOS as well as iOS. The compiler directive addresses the NSImage/UIImage difference. The code works with images placed in the assets catalog. The code is expanded to give you more context:

```
import SwiftUI

#if os(iOS)
public typealias CPImage = UIImage
#elseif os(OSX)
public typealias CPImage = NSImage
#endif

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var name = "star"
    
    var body: some View {
        GetImage(name: $name)
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
    }
}

struct GetImage: View {
    @Binding var name: String
    
    var body: some View {
        
        if CPImage(named: name) != nil {
            return Image(name).resizable()
        }
        
        return Image(systemName: name).resizable()
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it broken my modifiers. Can't use them on my view: MyImage( curToolBar.image ).resizable().aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit). I add my full code above in my question.

Comment: In SwiftUI, State and Binding property wrappers are being used to pass data between the ContentView and GetImage views. The MyImage view needs the same.

Comment: @Keith For your modifiers to work in MyImage(), resizable() is required so that the other modifiers will change the image. Like this: return Image( image ).resizable()  Then this will work: MyImage(image: $name).aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)

Comment: I removed that since it stretched out my icons.   I also had to change from button( name, image ) function signature to Button( action ) { image()} signature.  I'm guessing the padding between these function signatures have different behaviors??  Sorry, I'm so new to SwiftUI and the inconsistency in the APIs bugging me a lot.  Very little consistency.  Also compile errors are super bad I've had to write super small functions to get Xcode to communicate well to me.